# How to remove "data:" from the beginning of a JSON file with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

[From this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453320/invalid-json-primitive-error-when-converting-json-file/58375924?noredirect=1#comment121283211_58375924):

How does one remove the initial `data:` from a JSON file?

```
data: [
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

To make it look like this and be able to parse it properly.

```
[
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) reads a file *line by line*, which is wasted effort if the file's content is to be parsed *as a whole* as JSON.

  - The `-Raw` switch allows you to read the file *as a whole*, as a single, (usually) *multi-line* string.
- The following solution uses `-Raw` and recognizes and removes any property name at the start of the file followed by `:`

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath C:\path\path\file.json) -replace '^\w+:' |
  ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

First import the content of the file to a variable:

```
$json = gc -Path C:\path\path\file.json
```

Then (assuming this is in the first line of the file), replace the content of that line:

```
$json[0] = $json[0] -replace '^data:', ''
```

This will now work.

```
$json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Example:

```
# File content
data: [
    {
        "_id": "630528cd19c645e4f1c6be6d",
        "index": 0,
        "guid": "ee49651d-1296-4165-bada-6491ce6081a6"
    }
]

PS> $json = Get-Content -path somefile.json
PS> $json[0] = $json[0] -replace '^data:', ''
PS> $json | ConvertFrom-Json

_id                      index guid
---                      ----- ----
630528cd19c645e4f1c6be6d     0 ee49651d-1296-4165-bada-6491ce6081a6
```

Comment: A more general answer would be to go generic and do `$json[0] = $json[0] -replace '^[^\[]*'`. That'll remove everything before the initial `[` on that first line, not just 'data: '.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PowerShell [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) parser
(and [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) if even required to go back to `Json`):

```
$Data = @'
data: [
  {
    a: "..."
  },
  {
    a: "..."
  }
]
'@

(ConvertFrom-Json "{$data}").Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9

[
  {
    "a": "..."
  },
  {
    "a": "..."
  }
]
```